# Trace theorem for domains with lipschitz boundary

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I am looking for a reference where the trace theorem for domains with Lipschitz boundary is discussed. When the domain $\Omega$ has $C^1$ boundary there are classic references. What about a domain piecewise smooth or Lipschitz boundary?

Comment: Try "Alt, Linear Functional Analysis".

Comment: Look at Lions and Magenes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the references!